# Cron job and htaccess authentication

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, cron

I have a scheduled task setup in the server and the domain is under htaccess authentication mode.

So that's why the cron says "authorization failed"

Is there any way to put the username and password to the url I am specifying as a cron url?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can but the `username:password` separated by a colon in the URL:

```
http://username:password@example.com/path/to/file
```

as long as you are using [BASIC authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) as opposed to DIGEST authentication.